# Autodesk to ArcGIS Portal Connection limits loaded features in Civil 3D

Tags: arcgis-portal, connection, limitations, civil3d, autodesk

I am using the Autodesk Connector for ArcGIS in a Civil 3D project to connect to data my organization has stored in its ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. I have found that any vector layer I connect to using this tool will only load the first 500 features. This happens with both feature layers and map image layers. I'm not sure if there are limitations on raster layers in a similar way, but I have not noticed anything amiss other than possibly longer draw times.

This doesn't seem to be a graphical limit (such as Portal maps that will only display up to 2000 features), since the attribute table in Civil 3D will only have 500 features in it as well.

Interestingly, filtering out features with a query will not simply select from that initial first 500 that were loaded (which would yield <500 results) but instead loads the first 500 features from the overall dataset that fit the query, so I still end up with 500 features. In this case I'm using a point layer with ~12000 features, but it seems to be the case with any vector layer.

Having not found any documentation of this specific case, I'm not sure if this is simply a default setting somewhere that needs to be changed or an intended hard limitation on the software.

I am using:
ArcGIS Portal ver. 10.9.1
Autodesk Civil 3D 2023 ver. 13.5.131.0
Windows 11 Pro ver. 21H2

Comment: Feature services have a limit to the number of features they'll return in one go.  It's generally more than 500 by default, but there's no reason it couldn't have been set to 500.

Comment: @Vince, I'm seeing a MaxRecordCount of 2000 in the FeatureServer description for this dataset. Is there another place this might be set?